# Deriving a loss function properly accounting for different error type costs

Tags: classification, loss-functions, cross-entropy, sensitivity-specificity, false-positive-rate

*Consider a classification setting like a medical test: Not finding an existing health issue might be much worse (by a factor of 50) than assuming an issue when there is none.
I.e. a setting in which **false negatives are much worse than false positives** or vice versa.*

In classification, **cross entropy** is a very popular loss function with a solid theoretical foundation. However, it **does not consider different cost incurred by making a specific type of error**.

According to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/328432), simply adding a coefficient does not work as intended.

Do you know loss functions considering different severities of error types? I have not found any reference to such a function in my search.

I am aware of the fact that I could use **class balancing** and **sampling** techniques. However, I am not excited by the resulting model performance.
When I used a [different loss function](https://www.kaggle.com/rejpalcz/best-loss-function-for-f1-score-metric) however, the results were much better. The intuition behind the linked loss function is to use the f1-score, which is typically used as a metric as a loss function instead. Because the original metric does not possess the necessary mathematical properties of a loss functions, it is modified in way so that it does.
I then modified the linked "f1-loss" to this

[image: Generalized F-score],

in order to be able to penalize false negatives using the parameter beta  (when recall is given a higher weight, then the FN-rate will be lower).

Even though the results are much better (compared to class balancing), I would like to use a loss function which is not just a repurposed metric. Ideally, I hope to use a loss function which is proper in the sense that it accounts for the different costs **and** is theoretically justified.

The equivalent problem in a regression setting might be stated as different costs for over- or underestimating the target variable.